# Using OSRM with big queries?

Tags: osrm

I am experimenting with `table` service, the first restriction I thought about is the URL query length, as it work by http get request.

I need to send 5000 location, considering location is 35 characters long as for example:

> 35.921870470047,31.949649689353226;

thus, I will be sending `175000` character in the url, which is not possible I think for all browsers.

I will pass the result of durations matrix into the [vehicle routing problem solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/vehicle_routing) of Google Optimization Tools with the duarion matrix of a 5000 input location.

Here is an example of my query for small number of locations:

http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/35.921870470047,31.949649689353226;35.88357925415039,31.974007590177635;35.92055082321167,31.948830365146534

Any advice?

Comment: Well, I don't think it will solve the problem, but using a polyline may be shorter than the full coordinate. So if you use something like :

    curl 'http://router.project-osrm.org/table/v1/driving/polyline(egs_Iq_aqAppHzbHulFzeMe`EuvKpnCglA)?sources=0;1;3&destinations=2;4'

you'll be able to put more coordinates than with the full numbers.

Comment: For very large queries like these, the HTTP API is not the best fit. I would recommend using the Javascript node interface or the raw C++ library interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered [a similar issue](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/6612) and have received the advice to use the `--max-matching-size` parameter, when starting the osrm-routed program:

> docker run --name osrm -t -i -p 5000:5000 -v c:/repos:/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-routed --algorithm mld --max-matching-size 10000 /data/germany-latest.osrm